# Using Cloud Servers and Firewall

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, firewall, cloud

I would like to ask if the configuration of "firewall rules eg. only allowing port 80.. when configuring a server instance on cloud services such as google cloud and amazon aws is securely equivalent to hardware firewall implementations."

Are there settings or configuration on the "cloud instance firewall" cannot be achieved as compared to the hardware firewall?

Could someone help me clear this doubt that I can't be sure of? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how a `hardware firewall appliance` compares to a `virtual firewall appliance` and the `software firewall` on a operating system, or am I missing something and are you after something else?

Comment: @HBrujin I was referring to the "instance's firewall - for eg. at [google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall) as opposed to hardware firewalls. If they serve the same purpose, or could I say that they are securely equivalent since we can't put a hardware firewall on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

At high level and functionally they're mostly equivalent. In both cases the functionality will allow you to block or grant access to certain network ports to/from remote networks, regardless of how the server itself is configured.

The underlying technology could be fundamentally different i.e. rather than the [state-full packet inspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) that is the more common method in traditional firewalls, the software defined network typically associated with the cloud may be using the routing control plane to allow or deny certain flows.

Something you normally don't get to see with cloud firewall services is statistics on what is blocked.